# Oracle: how do I get a copy of the schema of the production DB onto a dev DB

Tags: oracle

My team does not have direct, command-line access to the oracle boxes but we have need to, from time to time, spin up dev instances of the DB.

We do not need the data, but we do need the layout.  Are there any tools that would interrogate an oracle instance and build a new instance?

Comment: This is ridiculous, if you don't have access to the tools necessary to copy the metadata easily then the person who does should either do it for you or give you the necessary access...

Comment: Also a little worrisome that you have schemas created but apparently the code is NOT in a source control system. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this tool.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/schema-compare-for-oracle/

We use the version for Sql Server in my shop and are very happy with it.

(I'm not affiliated with Red Gate, just a satisfied customer)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways...

You can do a schema export in TOAD and most other decent tools or you can write something using data pump

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php

for starters

Comment: @Ben: no it doesn't. You can also control it through SQL (using the `dbms_datapump` package)

Comment: +1 for datapump in network mode -- all you need is the db link.